# Divs not resizing with jQuery resize()

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dom, resize

I'm working with jQuery and Foundation framework. It's built into a Wordpress theme, that's why I have to use `"jQuery"` instead of the short hand `$` denotation.

jQuery resizes my slides upon loading the page. However it won't resize if I resize the browser window. I've tried lots of stuff but can't get it to work. *(border-box, separate functions, different syntax).*

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    var width = jQuery(window).width(),
        height = jQuery(window).height() - jQuery('.top-bar').height();
    jQuery('.slide').height(height).width(width);
    jQuery('.slide4 > div > img').height(height*.5);

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        jQuery('.slide').height(height).width(width);
        jQuery('.slide4 > div > img').height(height*.5);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code inside of a `resize` event and trigger it at page load. You can also use $ in you code using an IIF. You should definitely try to throttle the resizing, but this is cool for now!

```
// We can use $ inside here...
(function($){

  // When the document is ready this is called...
  $(function(){

    // We'll be using thise more than once!
    var $window = $(window);

    // Whenever a resize event occurs, do this...
    $window.on('resize', function(e){

      var width = $window.width(), 
          height = $window.height() - $('.top-bar').height();

      $('.slide').height(height).width(width);
      $('.slide4 > div > img').height(height*.5);

    // The "trigger" fakes the event on load...
    }).trigger('resize');


  })

})(jQuery); // You're passing jQuery to the IIF, so this is why you can use $ inside.
```

Hopefully this helps!